# Angular Material Dialog {hasBackdrop: false}

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog

I disabled the backdrop feature of an angular material dialog by setting {hasBackdrop: false} as the dialog configuration. So the dialog should not be close-able by clicking somewhere in the background.

This works. But now the background is operable! This should not be the case, only the dialog content should be operable.

Does anyone know how to configure this?

Comment: What do you mean by operable ?

Comment: This means that buttons and other elements, which belong to the background and not to the dialog can be handled (e.g. buttons can be pressed and so on).

Answer (score 2):

```
// We are setting disableClose to true, which means that the user will not be able to close the dialog just by clicking outside of it
// We are setting autoFocus to true, meaning that the focus will be set automatically on the first form field of the dialog
// hasBackdrop = false enables interacting with elements in the background for the MatDialog
const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
dialogConfig.hasBackdrop = false;
dialogConfig.data = {
  width: '500px',
  data: {title: 'My title'}
};
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogSearchComponent, dialogConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the styling of the backdrop, you can use `backdropClass` and remove the styling with your class.

If you want to disable the close modal when clicking on the backdrop or pressing esc, you can use `disableClose`.

Reference [dialog docs](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With 'disableClose' the dialog basically behaves like I expect it. Of course it would be nice (or better) to let the esc-functionality intact.

Comment: @KaiSchrader with disableClose you can control yourself how and when it should close. You could make a key event listener for `esc` key that will call the closeModal function.